# Server2012R2 - Get-NetIPAddress Missing?

Tags: powershell

I'm in the middle of trying to set a static source IP for a Server 2012R2 webserver using [This Powershell script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/24/use-powershell-to-change-ip-behavior-with-skipassource.aspx) but when I run the Get-NetIPAddres command I get 'the term Get-NetIPAddres' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet'.  If I run **Get-Command get-netip*** it only returns the following commands:

```
Function        Get-NetIPHttpsConfiguration                        NetworkTransition
Function        Get-NetIPHttpsState                                NetworkTransition
Function        Get-NetIPsecDospSetting                            NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetIPsecMainModeCryptoSet                      NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetIPsecMainModeRule                           NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetIPsecMainModeSA                             NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetIPsecPhase1AuthSet                          NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetIPsecPhase2AuthSet                          NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetIPsecQuickModeCryptoSet                     NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetIPsecQuickModeSA                            NetSecurity
Function        Get-NetIPsecRule                                   NetSecurity
```

From what I've read **Get-NetIPAddress** is part of the OS so would anyone have any idea why it wouldn't be available?

I've several other 2012 R2 servers that return results for Get-NetIPAddress and I'm stumped as to why this one server wouldn't have this command.

Comment: It looks like the NetTCPIP module isn't loaded. Does `Import-Module NetTCPIP` do anything?

Comment: That was the problem.  Running Import-Module NetTCPIP allowed me to run the command. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `Get-Module` you should see something like this:

```
    PS > Get-Module

    ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
    ---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
......
    Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetTCPIP                            {Find-NetRoute, Get-NetCompartment, Get-NetIPAddress, Get-...
```

Also, `Get-Command Get-NetIPAddress` gives more details about your cmdlet:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.SMIS> Get-Command Get-NetIPAddress

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Function        Get-NetIPAddress                                   NetTCPIP
```

After you run this last cmdlet the module should already be loaded. If not, you could run `Import-Module NetTCPIP` to load it, giving you access to the your command.