# Find NIC by IP address

Tags: powershell, ip-address, nic

I need to be able to find a NIC by IP address, whether full or partial. So writing something like:

```
Get-NIC-By-IP 10.10.*
```

Could return:

```
Ethernet
```

I know how to do this in Bash but haven't been able to find a PowerShell solution to this.

Comment: `Get-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 10.10* | select InterfaceAlias,IPAddress` if Get-NetIPAddress is available on the version used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the following command you will receive every interface which matches the IP-addres which you mention in the `match` clause.

```
Get-NetIPAddress | ?{ $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4" -and ($_.IPAddress -match "192.")} | Select-Object InterfaceAlias
```

In my case this is:

```
InterfaceAlias
--------------
Ethernet 2
Ethernet
```

Of course, you can modify the output if necessary.

**Supplement for old OS'es**

You can't run this script on old Windows browsers as the cmdlet isn't included according to this thread on TechNet: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dcc966a1-24c2-4ae4-b39d-b78df52b6aef/install-of-powershell-3-on-windows-7-seems-to-be-missing-modules?forum=winserverpowershell

> There are many cmdlets in Powershell for Windows 8 and Server 2012 (PS V3) that are not included in the V3 release for Windows 7.  An example would be Get-NetIPAddress, and many other network-related cmdlets.

Then again, it might be a good idea to upgrade the OS to a supported version (if possible of course).

Comment: Windows 7, PowerShell 5.1: Get-NetIPAddress : The term 'Get-NetIPAddress' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetIPAddress | ?{ $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4" -and ($_.IPAddress  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-NetIPAddress:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: My guess is `Get-NetIPAddress` isn't available on such an old OS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress?view=win10-ps It should be available on machines running Windows 8.1 or higher/similar if I read this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28815302/352640

Comment: Ah, didn't get the point you were trying to make :-) 

I had indeed assumed the OP was using a 'modern' version of the Windows OS.

Comment: The point is that you made an assumption concerning the environment which the querent didn't specify, and the assumption wasn't valid for at least one person looking at the question. Telling me to upgrade to a "supported" OS is inappropriate; many enterprises - mine included - have not yet qualified a version of Windows later than 7 for use.

Answer (score 2):

For versions of Windows and/or PowerShell that do not support `Get-NetIPAddress`, you can get the requisite information with a combination of the WMI queries for the classes `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` and `Win32_NetworkAdapter`:

```
$Configs = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='TRUE'" | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -like "192.168.*"}
ForEach ($Config in $Configs) {
    Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "Index=$($Config.Index)" | Select-Object NetConnectionID,Description
}
```